# What role, if any, do Archimedean valuations play in adic spaces?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, p-adic-analysis, rigid-analytic-geometry

I've been reading about adic spaces, and I couldn't help but wonder what would happen to the theory if one included in the definition of $Spa$ Archimedean valuations as well...?

Is there a weird Arakelov-type cousin of adic spaces? Would there be any merit for such a thing?

Comment: I guess the first question is: what is an Archimedean valuation? (with general value group)

Comment: You probably need to change the definition of affinoid ring $(A,A^+)$ so that $A^+$ is not a subring, but a multiplicative submonoid.  Otherwise, $\operatorname{Spa}(\mathbb{Z})$ lacks an archimedean branch.